# iOS - play video do I need to use an Observer

Tags: ios, avplayer

I have seen a couple of ways of player in video using AVKit and AVFoundation.

One approach constructs an AVPlayer object and invokes its play method.

The other approach creates an Observer of the "status" key and inside the observeValueForKeyPath method, it invokes the play method on the AVPlayer when the player.status = .ReadyToPlay.

Obviously the first approach is simpler.

Why would one use the second method to just play a video?

Thanks for your input